# Initialize LiveData later in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Having recently opted to use LiveData, I encounter a problem when initializing for a variable.
I have 2 Activities (I don't use Navigation but that's not the point) :

- One is a list with items fetch by API
- The other is a Detail Activity for the selected item in the previous list

The problem is that I need to be able to consult the Detail Activity in creation mode, i.e. in my ViewModel the object must not be retrieved via Retrofit but created via a new instantiation.

This is how it is done for now :

**Detail Activity :**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.details)

        val isNew = intent.extras?.getBoolean("new")
        if (isNew) {
            // Trigger lazy property
            viewModel.value
        } else {
            viewModel.getDetails()
        }

        presenter.value.observe(this, Observer { value ->
            value?.let {
                displayDetails(it)
            }
        })
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
class DetailsPresenter(private val repository: WorkOrderRepository)
    : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

    val value: MutableLiveData<Details> by lazy { MutableLiveData(Details("")) }

    fun getDetails() {
        RetrofitClient.getDetails()
        .onSuccess {
            this.value.value = it
        }

    }

}
```

The problem with this method is that my displayDetails() method is called twice.
One for lazy initialization and the other in case I'm looking at an existing item.

How can i initialize LiveData later in code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, it would be called two times, the first time is called because you register an observer in your View, which makes the `lazy` to work and create the `LiveData` object. The second time it gets called because the Retrofit updates the `LiveData` object. You are making a network request, they always take time to complete, until then, your program starts executing the next line (in your case it's setting up observer) while waiting for the request to complete.

It makes no sense to lazy initialize the `value` object if you are going to observe it regardless of the `if-else` condition.

I would make a retrofit call in the `init` block of the ViewModel and cache it there.

You can use `lateinit` keyword to later initialize the object.

```
lateinit var myLiveData: LiveData<T>
```

To check if `myLiveData` is initialized, just write `if (::myLiveData.isInitialized)`

Comment: What is `::myLiveData` I can't figure it out

Comment: I used it to access the reflection properties of `myLiveData` object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `lazy` won't create the second instance, `ViewModel` reference won't recreate.
So we can use the `Val value: LiveData<Details> = MutableLiveData()` instead of `lazy`.

You can add `getDetails()` method in `init` block itself to avoid the second call.